# How to use sed and wc command to handle whitespace

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sed, wc

If I have a CSV file and I want to know the number of columns, I'll use the following command:

```
  head -1 CSVFile.csv | sed 's/,/\t/g' | wc -w
```

However, whenever each column has a column name with a space in it, the command doesn't work and gives me a nonsense figure.

What would be the way to edit this command such that it gives me the correct number of columns?

e.g. in my file I could have column name `(t - ZK)` or `(e - 22)`

For example my file could be (first 2 row);

```
 ZZ(v - 1),Tat(t - 1000)
 1.1240128401924,2929292929
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the last line instead of the first. Change "head" to "tail". That would be a quick, easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the `sed` output to `wc -w` which would return the number of *words* in the output.  So if a field header contains spaces, those would be considered as different words.

You can use `awk`:

```
head -1 CSVFile.csv | awk -F, '{print NF}'
```

This would return the number of columns in the file (assuming the file is comma-delimited).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print NF; exit}' CSVFile.csv
```

---

If you wish to use chain of `head`, `sed` and `wc`

Try using `sed` replace deliminator as newline `\n` instead of tab `\t` and then count number of lines using `wc -l` instead of counting number of words with `wc -w`

```
head -1 CSVFile.csv | sed 's/,/\n/g' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ane 'print scalar(@F)-1 if($.==1)' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no "," in header name  (like field1,"Surname,name",field3, ...)

```
sed "1 s/[^,]//g;q" CSVFile.csv | wc -c
```

Could also be made only in sed but a bit heavy for counting.